# tabcontrol selectedindex changed event not getting fired C#

Tags: c#

hey guys, i have very small issue please see the code below

```
// this is main load
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    tabAddRemoveOperator.SelectedIndex = 0;
}

//this is selected index changed event method
private void tabAddRemoveOperator_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (tabAddRemoveOperator.SelectedIndex == 0)
           //someCode;
    else if (tabAddRemoveOperator.SelectedIndex == 1)
           //someCode;
}
```

My problem is, i'm changing the `tab selectedindex` on `form_load` method so `tab_selectedindexchanged` Event should get fired right ? but it isn't..

I have googled about this issue, so i found a thread saying that untill your controls are loaded their event fill not get fired, but i dn't think it is correct, coz all controls are get loaded n initialized in constructor only.. so i'm confused here with this issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**The `SelectedIndexChanged` event is never raised because the *default* `SelectedIndex` is 0.** When you set the `SelectedIndex` to 0 in the form's `Load` event handler, the selected index doesn't actually change to a new value, so the event is never getting raised.

There are two possible workarounds for this that come to mind:

1. You could refactor the initialization code for the case where `SelectedIndex == 0` out to another method, and then call that method both from the `SelectedIndexChanged` event handler and from the form's `Load` event handler.
2. You could set the `SelectedIndex` to an index other than 0 in the `Load` event handler, and then immediately set it back to 0. This will cause the `SelectedIndex` value to change twice, but will have the expected result.

Answer (score 3):

I had almost the same issue (in my case I was setting the SelectedIndex in the form's constructor, but I was using a non-zero value - and the SelectedIndexChanged event did not fire).

I put a Timer on the form with a short delay, enabled it in the constructor, after the InitializeComponent call. In the timer's Tick event, I disabled the timer (so that it only happened once) and set the tab control's SelectedIndex there (and the SelectedIndexChanged event did fire).

```
    public MainForm(string[] args)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        // tabControl1.SelectedIndex = 2; // Did not fire
        OnceAtStartupTimer.Enabled = true;
    }

    private void OnceAtStartupTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OnceAtStartupTimer.Enabled = false;
        tabControl1.SelectedIndex = 2;
    }


    private void tabControl1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Code to run when SelectedIndex changes            
    }
```

Comment: Looking at the `SelectedIndex` handler at [referencesource.microsoft.com](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#q=tabcontrol) reveals that `TabControl` will not fire some events when it is in early stages with it's [Control.IsHandleCreated](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.ishandlecreated%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property not set. So your way to delay the action makes sense

Answer (score 0):

Have you registered the event? Something like:

```
tabAddRemoveOperator.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(tabAddRemoveOperator_SelectedIndexChanged);
```

Answer (score 0):

I came up with another way to force a SelectedIndexChanged event to fire in the form_load. Set DeselectTab() in the form_load to the last tab on the control. Deselecting the last tab will cause the index to move to tab 0 and generate the SelectedIndexChanged event.